# How add own javascript file to nanoc?

Tags: javascript, url-routing, haml, nanoc

again I have a problem with files in nanoc. This time I wanted to attach custom file `slide.js` to my blog but I cannot (don't know why - probably something is wrong with my routes). Here's my routes:

```
compile '/js/*/' do
  # don’t filter or layout
end

...

route '/js/*/' do
  /'js'/ + item.identifier.chop + '.js'
end
```

And in the `head` section of my layout I've put: `%script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "/js/slide.js"}/` (yes, it's a HAML).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? It would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, I think I've solved it:

```
compile '/javascripts/*/' do
  nil
end

...

route '/javascripts/*/' do
    item.identifier.chop + ".js"
end
```

If anyone knows better solution, feel free to put it here.

Comment: Instead of using ".js" you can also use `item[:extension]`, which is the original file extension. Additionally, the `#compile` block does not need to return anything, so the `nil` is not useful.